# PayPal sandbox recurring payment error: The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have paypal sandbox account. Everything works fine for single payments - I set business=test@gmail.com and make a payment using ..._biz@gmail.com account which was created under "Test Accounts" menu of the sandbox. However when I try to do the same for recurring payments, I get an error. At first everything looks fine - I get redirected to paypal where I can see the detail of subscription but when I try to sign in with ..._biz@gmail.com, it redirects me to a page that says: The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: It sounds like your configuration is invalid; make sure your PDT token is correct and that the form values you are submitting are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am not fully sure what exactly was wrong but in case someone else has the same problem and stumbles on this question: all I had to do is re-create both seller and buyer test accounts from under my main sandbox account. The accounts that I tested on seemed valid but they were created many months (if not years) ago so probably paypal had some wrong (i.e. old) configs associated with them. The newly created accounts work just fine.